# 1. Field not found : description

Tags: jasper-reports

'<'jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="productsExport" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="b6f96e0c-32ea-431c-b1db-cf8582bb9a6f">

```
</jasperReport>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although it's not very detailed info, I think you have an error when try to compile (preview) your report in Jaspersoft Studio / iReport which sais: "Field not found: desrciption ---- net.sf (blabla)"

Very simple to fix: It only occurs( for as far as I know) when you have a reference in your report (example a Text Field) to a field from the Dataset (SQL query or manual field) that isn't there anymore.
Probably a new query, updated the fields and the field 'Description' dissappeared.

How to solve:

- Remove the reference (Text Field probably) in your report with "$F{description}. OR
- Update Dataset (SQL Query) so that if has the field 'description' as a result  OR
- (Ugly, not usefull but working): Add the field manually